# some question about redux-toolkit redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I have a project that use redux-toolkit and redux-saga it is working fine now.
but now i have some question do I need to use redux-saga.

1. one of most feature I use redux-saga because it has a side effect.
   if I dispatch an action on redux after the reducer executes
   It can execute another saga function.

```js
  yield all([
    takeEvery<any>(boardAcctions.addWidget.type, updateWidgetUI),
    takeEvery<any>(boardAcctions.moveWidget.type, updateWidgetUI),
    takeEvery<any>(boardAcctions.updateWidgetConfig.type, updateWidgetUI),
    takeEvery<any>(boardAcctions.removeWidget.type, updateWidgetUI),
  ])
```

2. on saga function you can dispatch another action so if you have multiple actions need to update it will be very easy with saga.

```js
    yield put(loginActions.updateUser(userdata))
    yield put(dashboardAction.updateBoard(dashboarData))
```

but on redux-toolkit with function createAsyncThunk().
I can't dispatch another action. even on extra reduces it just only a reducer and I think dispatch another action inside that is not illegal

how do I do that without redux-saga?

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can dispatch other actions from within `createAsyncThunk`.

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/fetchByIdStatus',
  async (userId, { dispatch }) => {

    dispatch(someOtherAction())

  }
)
```

Comment: thank i will try that do you have any idea how to listen to an action and dispatch another async  action after the reducer finish the first action

Comment: that's not possible with thunks. You can just have a normal thunk that dispatches two other thunks with an `await` in-between though.